# How to include charset in Vcard written using EZ-Vcard?

Tags: java, character-encoding, vcf-vcard

I am using the [EZ-VCards library][1] to generate some VCard data in a Java webapp.

It works fine and is quite straight-forward to use, except for encoding issues. The values are written using UTF-8 (I checked using a hex editor), but the encoding is not explicitely specified in the vcard.

As a result, when imported in a client program such as Outlook or the Contacts app in OSX, the accented characters are mis-reprensented. If the charset is specified, the values are imported correctly.

What I get :

```
FN:André Müller
```

What I would like to have :

```
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:André Müller
```

How can I add this charset information using EZ-Vcard ? I read the doc (examples) and the JavaDoc API but could not find the way to do it.

**EDIT:** Michael's answer replied my original question, but unfortunately Outlook just won't play nice with UTF-8. So I need to encode in ISO-8859-1. I managed to manually create the a vcard string that works and imports correctly in Outlook as well as Apple Contacts and it looks like this :

```
N;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:André;Müller;;; 
FN;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:André Müller
```

At the web controller level, I ensure that the string that is returned is indeed encoded in iso-8859-1.

So how can I achieve this using EZ-Vcard ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using quoted-printable encoding:

```
VCard vcard = new VCard();
FormattedName fn = vcard.setFormattedName("André Müller");
fn.getParameters().setEncoding(Encoding.QUOTED_PRINTABLE);
fn.getParameters().setCharset("ISO-8859-1");
vcard.write(System.out);
```

Prints:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN;ENCODING=quoted-printable;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:Andr=E9 M=FCller
PRODID:ez-vcard 0.9.8
END:VCARD
```

Please let me know if this works!

Comment: This works (generates the correct encoding) but Outlook is not able to understand it. It shows the name as "AndrÃ© MÃ¼ller".

Comment: I think Outlook will only understand ISO-8859-1 or win 1252... I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @PierreHenry I updated my answer.  You can specify the character set you want to use by setting the CHARSET parameter.

Comment: @Michale : thanks, that's probably what I needed. I'll try it out later and accept if it works.